# Remove a char from Iterable<Map<String, Object>> in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, iterator, iteration

In my code I am using,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getBlueprintById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody BlueprintsMessage find(@FormDataParam("id") String id, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    ResponseStatus status = null;
    Long blueprintId = Long.parseLong(id);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    Iterable<Map<String, Object>> entity = null;
    try {
        entity = blueprintService.getBlueprintById(blueprintId);

        status = new ResponseStatus(ResponseStatusCode.STATUS_OK, "SUCCESS");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new BlueprintsMessage(status, entity);
}
```

and the output value was,

```
{
  "blueprint": {        
    "relation": [
      {
        "id": 1271,
        "relationParam": [
          {
            "value": "{\"canaries\":\"1\",\"canary_watch_time\":\"30000-180000\",\"update_watch_time\":\"30000-180000\",\"max_in_flight\":\"4\"}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to remove `\` in my output and the output was same as `Iterable<Map<String, Object>>` type. The values saved into database, i just get the values from DB.

Comment: How do you generate your output?

Comment: I just get the values from database.

Comment: Show us how are you printing your output.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/getBlueprintById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody BlueprintsMessage find(@FormDataParam("id") String id) {
  ResponseStatus status = null;
  Long blueprintId = Long.parseLong(id);
 
  Iterable<Map<String, Object>> entity = null;
  try {
   entity = blueprintService.getBlueprintById(blueprintId);
   status = new ResponseStatus(ResponseStatusCode.STATUS_OK, "SUCCESS");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return new BlueprintsMessage(status, entity);
 }

Comment: @Karthikeyan kindly edit your question and add the code in question only.

Comment: Actually this is my full method once i call /getBlueprintById from post man means it return a output value.

Comment: 1/ your output is a String, not something else, 2/ the \ are here because `"` is the string delimiter in java, so you have to escape it to use it in a string.

Comment: output is not a string. It was Iterable<Map<String, Object>> type.